# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. The docker daemon is running?

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to work with Continuous Integration using Gitlab but I have some problems. I installed gitlab runner. I precise both gitlab runner and gitlab work with docker containers. But I got the following problem :

`Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon ru nning? (docker.go:1027:0s)`

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
image: python:latest

variables:
  SECRET_KEY: "mykey"
  DEBUG: "True"
  ALLOWED_HOSTS: "['*']"
  DB_ENGINE: "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"
  DB_NAME: "citest"
  DB_USER: "admin"
  DB_PASSWORD: "password"
  DB_HOST: "localhost"
  STATIC_URL: "/static/"

# This folder is cached between builds
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
  paths:
    - ~/.cache/pip/

before_script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  
test:
  script:
    - cd backend
    - python3 manage.py makemigrations
    - python3 manage.py migrate
    - python3 manage.py test
```

Do you have any ideas to solve that problems ? Thank you very much !

Comment: I think this just means you quit docker and need to reopen it, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the following two methods will solve the problem.
you need to configure docker service for executing Docker commands without `sudo`
use [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-debian-10#step-2-%E2%80%94-executing-the-docker-command-without-sudo-optional) article.
you have another way. if you install docker with Root user. you need to grant root privilege for gitlab-ruuner user.
open  `/etc/sudoers` and Add this line at the end of the file.

```
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I hope I could help you.
Regards